# How to import stuff in java with Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, class, visual-studio-code, package

Im new with Java and i'm struggling with packages and classes when it comes to imports.
So i want to do something simple :

I want to include my class that takes inputs from the user, but somehow it keeps giving me all sorts of errors.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your Clavier class? Does it exist in the path specified on the error log?

Comment: what do u mean by share? As you can see on the left of the screen, Clavier.java exists inside of myclass

Comment: Yes, we can see that there is a file there. What are its contents? The message "bad source file: ./myclass/Clavier.java" tends to indicate that the IDE found the file, but that the Clavier class is not in it. I assume you meant to put it there; if you want our help, we need to know what's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, to be part of a package, you both need to be inside the correct folder, and start the file with `package myclass;`. You didn't show us the source code for `Clavier.java` but my educated guess is that you didn't start it with `package myclass;`.

As a side note, `myclass` is a really bad and confusing name for a package (which isn't a class).

Comment: You are right!! thankyou, i should rename myclass to mypackage its less confusing, i added package mypackage inside of clavier.java and it worked fine